# Regex to Match Number from Sequence of Specific N-digit Numbers

Tags: regex

I have a series of numbers: `[1, 4, 8, 16]`

I need to determine if a number matches any of those.

My regex now is:

`(1|4|8|16)`

This matches the `1`, `4`, or `8` fine but, for the `16`, it stops after the `1`.

If I use `(16)` it will detect the 16 correctly but, obviously, not work to detect anything else.

My question is why the `16` in the first regex pattern stops detection after the `1` but the second pattern matches the full number.

Also, how to create a pattern that will match any of the digits to one in the collection correctly, regardless of how many digits they may be. i.e. 2, 3, 4+ not just 1 and/or 2, such that I could check within a collection as such `[1, 64, 128, 1024]` and match any number.

**UPDATE**

Also, I need to be able to extract the entire value in a capture group not just detect presence.

**Update**

The problem seems to be that the `1` in the `16` is matching the `1` and not proceeding to check the next letter before declaring a match with the single `1` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why the 16 in the first regex pattern stops detection after the 1 but the second pattern matches the full number?

Because `(1|4|8|16)` that matches the `1` of `16` by `1|` then regex-engine stops searching.
Try `(16|4|8|1)` to matches both `1` and `16`

How to create a pattern that will match any of the digits to one in the collection?

Try this regex:
`[0-9]+`  or `\d+`

OR in a capture group:
`([0-9]+)`  or `(\d+)`

See example https://regex101.com/r/40jdiq/1 and https://regex101.com/r/40jdiq/2

Comment: Is simply re-ordering the numbers to start from those longest in length the defacto approach? Re: a blanket digital match - my use-case has restrictions on which digits can be matched.